# Chronometer showing just minutes and hours

Tags: android

My Android Studio chronometer is just showing minutes and hours like this 0.0 and I wanted just seconds and minutes. How can I achieve this.
My code for Java is like this.

```
 final Chronometer chrono = 
(Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
chrono.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code snippet.

```
Chronometer timeElapsed = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronomete); 

timeElapsed.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer cArg) {
        long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - cArg.getBase();
        int h   = (int)(time /3600000);
        int m = (int)(time - h*3600000)/60000;
        int s= (int)(time - h*3600000- m*60000)/1000 ;
        String hh = h < 10 ? "0"+h: h+"";
        String mm = m < 10 ? "0"+m: m+"";
        String ss = s < 10 ? "0"+s: s+"";
        cArg.setText(hh+":"+mm+":"+ss);
    }
});
timeElapsed.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
timeElapsed.start();
```

Customize it as you like.

Comment: Please mark as answer correct, it it found helpful to you. Cheers :)